# What is the lowest level of permissions required to add users to a site SP2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions

I've inherited an SharePoint 2013 instance that has a Site Collection with multiple sites beneath it. Each of these sites needs to have different users associated with it and is managed by a different person (!!) as the sites are geographically based.

I need to know what the bare minimum of permissions is required to allow for users to be added to a site.

Currently, everyone that needs to be able to add users to the sites is being added to the site collection administrators and this is a disaster waiting to happen.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give them full control to their respective sites...check this technet for more details:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721640.aspx